# Exporting variables and dataframes in main script to imported script for usage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and struggling with maybe a simple issue:

I have a main script called A_script.py. In it is the following code (simplified and anonymised):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pandas as pd
    df_A = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM [xxx].[xx].[xxxxx]', conn)
    A_len = len(df_A.index)
    
    #import script B_script.py
    import B_script
```

B_script contains the following code:

```
from A_script import df_A
from A_script import A_len
```

This code in B_script errors when I run the script A_script, as it cannot bring in the variable and the dataframe. How do I get around this, without having to rerun the entire A_script from within B_script that creates df_A and A_len, which is significantly larger and more complex than the example?

Comment: it looks like you have a circular import. Script B depends on Script A, which depends on Script B, etc. If you need to run both scripts together, then I would suggest splitting out the "run" part into an independent script. That way A can be independent and B can depend on A, while your new script can depend on both.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but when you run your A_script, somewhere along the line it imports the B_script which in it's turn imports some stuff from A_script?!

Answer (score 0):

Two points.

First, you're doing a circular import. A_script is importing B_script and B_script is importing A_script. Change this. If both files depend on code from each other, then refactor, create a new file, and put the needed functions, and import from there.

Point number two, in A_script, your code is in an if clause `if __name__ == '__main__'`. When you import a module, `__name__` is *not* `__main__`. It only is if the file is run directly. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

So I guess currently you're getting an error saying that `df_A` and `A_len` is not found in A_script. That's because that code is never run. So remove the if clause.

```py
import pandas as pd
df_A = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM [xxx].[xx].[xxxxx]', conn)
A_len = len(df_A.index)
```

Comment: Thanks! So A_script is not dependant on B_script, it is just importing the script to run B_script. B_script is dependant on variables and dfs from A_script. If I remove the if clause, does B_script rerun A_script, as that is not what I want to happen...

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to "run B_script"? And what do you mean by rerun A_script?